# Data-Icon attribute in Jquery Mobile produces black circle with no logo?

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
    <a href="index.html" data-theme="b" data-icon='gear'>Switch</a>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="landing.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>
</div>
```

No gear or home icons show. I dont get it. Here are files used, all newest.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hosting the CSS locally which means you need to also host the CSS images locally.

Either use the jQuery CDN for your CSS which will also use the CDN hosted images or make sure you have an `image` directory under your `css` directory: `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css`

There should be an `images` directory under your `css` directory with the following files:

- ajax-loader.png
- icons-18-black.png
- icons-18-white.png
- icons-36-black.png
- icons-36-white.png

Comment: @user1094441 You're welcome. On a side-note, I would always use the CDN but the jQuery CDN does not support `https` protocol so if you want to use your site over a secure connection then you have to host them yourself.